# Python, Selenium: How to get text next to element

Tags: python, selenium, cell

I'm fairly new to selenium and I'm trying to get the text of a cell next to a known element.

This is an excerpt of a webtable:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
        text-to-copy
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <input type="text" size="10" id="known_id" onchange="update(this.id);" onclick="setElementId(this.id);"/>
        X
    </div>
    <div class="cell right">
        <div id="some_id">?</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It looks something like this:

[image]

From this table I would like to get the `text-to-copy` with `selenium`. As the composition of the table can vary, there is no way to know that cells `xpath`. Therefore I can not use `selenium_driver.find_element_by_xpath()`. The only known thing is the id of the cell next to it (`id=known_id`).

The following pseudo code is to illustrate what I'm looking for:

```
element = selenium_driver.find_element_by_id("known_id")
result = element.get_visible_text_from_cell_before_element()
```

Is there a way to get the visible text (`text-to-copy`) with `selenium`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can fairly use `xpath`, all other `locators` that `Selenium supports` `would not work`, becasue we have to traverse **upward in DOM.**

The below xpath is dependent on `known_id`

```
//input[contains(@id,'known_id')]/../preceding-sibling::div
```

You have to either use `.text` or `.get_attribute` etc to get the text.

**Sample code :**

```
time.sleep(5)
element = selenium_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'known_id')]/../preceding-sibling::div").get_attribute('innerText')
print(element)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right! Weirdly the tags switched from `div` to `td` (this might be normal, I have no clue about html). The command `element = selenium_driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'known_id')]/../preceding-sibling::td").text` works wonderful. Thanks