# Selenium: How to locate the element with text Run Insight

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am automating an internal company webpage that loads its HTML dynamically with javascript. I have been trying to find the XPath for automating a click action (which I did), but somehow while running the script selenium throws an error:

```
Unable to locate element
```

The Html content is below:

```
<mat-nav-list _ngcontent-gki-c5="" class="mat-nav-list mat-list-base" dense="" role="navigation">
      <div _ngcontent-gki-c5="" class="mat-subheading-1 ng-tns-c5-1" style="">Insights</div>

      <!----><a _ngcontent-gki-c5="" class="mat-list-item mat-focus-indicator ng-tns-c5-1 ng-star-inserted" mat-list-item="" href="/insights/home"><div class="mat-list-item-content" style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;">
  <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" style="">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mat-list-text" style=""></div>
        Your Highlights
</div>
</a><a _ngcontent-gki-c5="" class="mat-list-item mat-focus-indicator ng-tns-c5-1 ng-star-inserted" mat-list-item="" href="/insights/downloads"><div class="mat-list-item-content" style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;">
  <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" style="">
  </div>
    
  <div class="mat-list-text" style=""></div>
        Downloads
      
</div>
</a>
      <a _ngcontent-gki-c5="" class="mat-focus-indicator ng-tns-c5-1 mat-list-item menu-item text-neutral-l1 font-size-sub-1 active" mat-list-item="" style=""><div class="mat-list-item-content" style="background: rgb(204, 136, 136); border: 2px solid red;">
  <div class="mat-list-item-ripple mat-ripple" mat-ripple="" style="">
  </div>
          
  <div class="mat-list-text" style=""></div>
        Run Insight
        <mat-icon _ngcontent-gki-c5="" class="mat-icon notranslate ng-tns-c5-1 material-icons ng-trigger ng-trigger-indicatorRotate mat-icon-no-color" role="img" aria-hidden="true" data-mat-icon-type="font" style="transform: rotate(180deg);"> expand_more </mat-icon>
</div>
</a>
      <!----><!---->
        <mat-form-field _ngcontent-gki-c5="" class="cds-mt-4 w-100 inner-icon-prefix mat-form-field ng-tns-c9-6 mat-primary ng-tns-c5-1 mat-form-field-type-mat-input mat-form-field-appearance-legacy mat-form-field-can-float mat-form-field-should-float mat-form-field-has-label mat-form-field-hide-placeholder ng-pristine ng-valid ng-star-inserted ng-touched" style=""><div class="mat-form-field-wrapper">
  <div class="mat-form-field-flex">
    <!---->
  </div>
        </div>
        </mat-form-field>
</mat-nav-list>
```

I want to click on the text "*Run insight*" from the dynamically generated list. The xpaths that I used are:

```
//a[@class='mat-focus-indicator ng-tns-c5-1 mat-list-item menu-item text-neutral-l1 font-size-sub-1 active']
//div[contains(text(),'Run Insight')]
//div[contains(@class, 'mat-list-item-content') and normalize-space(text()) = 'Run insight']
```

Is there a better XPath for the "*Run insight*" click action? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, Selenium: How to get text next to element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69090181/python-selenium-how-to-get-text-next-to-element)

Comment: Not really. The elements are inside the iframe which takes a bit long to load. How do I select the element to be clicked?

Comment: @LibinThomas : You need to switch to iframe first, In order to access the element, which is inside the iframe. Without switching to iframe you won't be able to access the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so to click on the element with text as ***Run Insight*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Run Insight"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//mat-nav-list//a[@mat-list-item]//div[@class='mat-list-item-content' and contains(., 'Run Insight')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: This worked like charm! Thanks a ton. Don't know how my previous comment disappeared :(